# MySQL Limit amount of records returned between 2 dates

Tags: mysql, date-range, linegraph

I'm afraid I with this situation:

- I have a MySQL table with just 3 columns: ID, CREATED, TOTAL_VALUE.
- A new TOTAL_VALUE is recorded roughly every 60 seconds, so about 1440 times a day.
- I am using PHP to generate some CanvasJS code that plots the MySQL records into line graph - this so that I can see how TOTAL_VALUE changes over time.

it works great for displaying 1 day worth of data, but when doing 1 week(7*1440=10080 plot points) things get really slow.

And a date range of for example 1-JAN-2016 and 1-SEP-2016 just leads to time outs in the PHP script.

How can I write some MySQL that still selects records between a date range but limit the rows returned to ie max 1000 rows?

I need to optimize this by limiting the number of data points that need to be plotted.

Can MySQL do some clever stuff where it decides to skip 1 every so many rows and return 1000 averaged values - this so that my line graph would by approximation still be correct- but using fewer data points?

Comment: MySQL can limit rows but it will not help you because it will give you requested number of rows in one sequence that will not cover the entire requested period.  What you need to do is to create an event that runs periodically, say every day and that creates a weekly summary and stores in another table. Then when your query is limited to a short date span then pull the data from the primary table and when the requested date span is larger than a threshold, retrieve data from the summarized table (that basically includes average of the week).

Comment: Some interesting math based on ID modulus or matches to only certain seconds may help.  You could also calculate "minutely", "hourly", "daily" averages to another table at end of day or something like that.  ID example: `WHERE /* date query */ AND ID % 60 = 0`.  Maybe not as accurate as average but it may speed things up.